# flutter local notifications send ID with payload option

Tags: flutter, localnotification

I have an application that stores data with sqflite. I access the records that I list with listview from the detail page with the constructor method. Short and simple codes are as follows.

*notes.dart --> main page*

```
 child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: notes.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return NoteClass(
                                  notes: notes[index],
                                  );
                            },
                          ),
```

---

*note_class.dart* -->

```
  return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Dismissible(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            movementDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            background: Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 38),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Icon(
                    LineIcons.trash,
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                    size: 27,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              _deleteNote(widget.notes.noteID);
            },
            child: Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 2),
              elevation: 2,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
              child: Container(
                height: 80,
                child: ListTile(
                  onTap: (){
                    _detailPage(context, widget.notes);
                  },
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5),
                  title: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 17),
                        child: Icon(Icons.note)
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 45),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment:
                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              crossAxisAlignment:
                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      widget.notes.noteHeader,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 19,
                                          color: Colors.grey[900]),
                                    )),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                                  child: Text(
                                     widget.notes.noteBody,
                                    style:  TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 17,
                                        color: Colors.grey[900]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )),
      ],
    );



_detailPage(BuildContext context, NoteModel noteModel) {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageTransition(
            type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
            child: NoteDetail(
              content: noteModel,
            )));
  }
```

---

*note_detail.dart*

```
Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Card(
                          elevation: 3,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            height: 50,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 0),
                            child: SelectableText(
                              widget.content.noteHeader,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.grey[800],),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Card(
                          elevation: 3,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            height: 50,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 0),
                            child: SelectableText(
                              widget.content.noteBody,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.grey[800],),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),],
                    ),
```

---

On the note detail page I set notifications with flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule and I can view note details with notifications. But when I click on the notification I want to go to the detail page of the related note. I sent the ID of the record with the payload parameter.

---

Then, I added the onSelectNotification method in notes.dart.

```
Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {

######## what should I write here? ########

    }
  }
```

---

There is an ID value in payload. How can I access the note detail about ID information. Or click on the notification in which way I can go to the note detail page.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. All you have to do is something similar to this:

```
class NoteDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final String payload;
  NoteDetail (this.payload);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => NoteDetailState(payload);

}
class NoteDetailState extends State {
 String payload;
 NoteDetailState (this.payload);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar()
  body:Column( your column code here))
  }
// call this after something
void save() {
  //dosomething
  // go back to the old page 
  // notice the true, if all goes good with save send true otherwise false
  Navigator.pop(context, true);
 }
}

// use this code to go to detail
void navigateToDetail(String payload) async {
bool result = await Navigator.push(context, 
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NoteDetail(payload)),
);
if (result == true) {
  getData(); // refresh data from db
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of the payload variable?
All the notes list elements?

Comment: you can send both ways think of the 2 sql tables note and notedetail lets say its one to many relation ship  ie one note can have many details, so you send all the details to your details page or you could send the noteId which is a primary key in notedetail table, I know I am giving more broader example. I would go with method 2 send the key so in your case the payload  would be some uniqueidentifier  noteid